# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) while using GMP library

Tags: c, gmp

I have a problem with the following function. I am trying to implement the "exponentiation by squaring", which is a general method for fast computation of large positive
integer powers of a number.

```
unsigned long EBS(mpz_t &m, mpz_t g, mpz_t k, mpz_t p) {
        mpz_t y, carre, a;
        mpz_init(y);
        mpz_set_ui(carre, 2);

        if(mpz_cmp_si(k, 0) < 0) {
            mpz_set_ui(a, 1);
            mpz_cdiv_q(g, a, g);
            mpz_mul_si(k, k, -1);
        }
        if(mpz_cmp(k, 0) == 0) {
            mpz_set_ui(m, 1);
            return mpz_get_ui(m);
        }
    
        mpz_set_ui(y, 1);
        
        while (mpz_cmp_si(k, 1) > 0) {
            if(mpz_even_p(k) != 0) {
                mpz_powm(g, g, carre, p);
                mpz_set_si(k, (mpz_get_si(k) / 2));
            }
            else {
                mpz_mul(y, g, y);
                mpz_mul(g, g, g);
                mpz_set_si(k, ((mpz_get_si(k) - 1) / 2));
            }
        }
        mpz_mul(m, g, y);
        
        return mpz_get_ui(m);
 }
```

When I call the function from `main()` :

```
int main() {
   mpz_t M,c;
   mpz_init(M);
   mpz_init(c);

   .....

 const char* mess = random_String();
 char c_str[1000];
 std::cout << "Le message à chiffrer : " << mess << std::endl;
 mpz_set_str(M, mess, 10);
 EBS(c, M, e, n); //I call the function from here

}
```

When I call the function `EBS`, I get an `Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)` and I don't understand why.
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Usually this is the result of using a bad pointer or accessing an array or C string out of bounds. Are you sure 1000 is enough? Is that even used?

Comment: Don't tag this question `C++` if you're using GMP's C interface.

Comment: Don't you have to initialize the GMP integers before you assign to them? See [5.1 Initializing integers](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers), and also 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you mean in the main() function or EBS?

Comment: Passsing the `m` like `mpz_t &m` does not make any sence since `mpz_t` is 1-element array and decays to a pointer when passed to a function. So you modify the passed value anyway.

Comment: Also `mpz_cmp(k, 0)` should be `mpz_cmp_si(k, 0)`.

Comment: Have you read the sections of the manual that I referenced? If so, then look at your code `mpz_set_ui(carre, 2);` and see if you can understand why that's wrong because you haven't initialized `carre`.